# When using a 3rd party uninstaller on Windows, should I postpone reboot until after the leftover files are removed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, uninstall

I'm using GeekUninstaller, because it's free and has pretty good reviews.

Usually, I will choose the program I want to uninstall, go through the regular uninstallation process, and then GeekUninstaller will scan my computer for leftover files, and offer to remove them.

In some cases, after I complete the standard uninstaller process, the uninstaller of the program I just removed will give me a prompt: "please restart your computer so that leftover files can be removed". This happens right before GeekUninstaller is able to start its scan for leftover files. If I choose to restart, GeekUninstaller won't get its chance to run its post-uninstall scan.

In these cases, are the "leftover files" that the program's uninstallation process removes on reboot the same as the files that GeekUninstaller (or similar uninstaller) will look for in its scan for "leftover files"?

If I postpone the reboot, let GeekUninstaller scan and do its cleanup magic, and then reboot my computer, does whatever cleanup operation that is supposed to happen during reboot still happen?

If I want to remove as many traces of the program from my computer as possible, what should I do?

Comment: Is there an option to scan for leftovers **after** the reboot?  Because the GeekUninstaller's "leftover files" might point to the files scheduled to be removed after the reboot, which will do more harm than good.

Comment: @Rysa I don't think there is that option, no. Why would it do more harm than good to remove the leftovers before reboot?

Comment: Because when it says to reboot, it sets an 'instruction' to remove the files during the reboot process, normally because such files are in use when you're already booted into Windows. By removing the files in Windows using Geek, you might end up deleting the 'instructions' causing the files-in-use not to be deleted instead. Or during reboot the files cannot be found since Geek has already deleted them.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't use uninstaller programs unless for programs that are notoriously hard to completely remove from the system.

Answer (score 1):

If an uninstaller is asking for a reboot it is mostly just to cleanup stuff that could potentially still be in use by the system. To prevent garbage it offers to reboot and will delete the files on either shutdown or the next reboot.

If GeekUninstaller offers to remove the files too, then there won't be any harm the uninstaller may cause. It is by definition impossible to delete a file that doesn't exist.
It actually may remove additional stuff that GeekUninstaller did not notice, like certain registry keys.

So in short, the answer to your question: **Yes, you can safely postpone the reboot.**

However, there is always a chance that both the default uninstaller and GeekUninstaller will miss files or registry keys which stay behind. If you really want to clean your computer, run some cleaning tools.
And even then you cannot be sure. The only possible way to make sure your computer is fully clean of the program is to reinstall your OS.

NOTE: do not do this with Windows updates, they are kind of special and have dependencies your system relies on and may cause trouble.